# How to wrap part of the text with span tag using jquery (wordpress)?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, text

I need to wrap Private:  with span tag.
I tried following codes but it doesn't show  (no error in console).
Would you please let me know how to wrap it with span?

Existing code (created using plugin):

```
<div class="dwqa-question-item dwqa-status-open">
     <header class="dwqa-question-title">
          <a href="https://www.myweb.com/question/%ed%85>Private: Question 1</a>
     </header>
</div>
<div class="dwqa-question-item dwqa-status-open">
     <header class="dwqa-question-title">
          <a href="https://www.myweb.com/question/%ed%88>Private: Question 2</a>
</header>
</div>
```

Codes I tried:

```
jQuery(".dwqa-question-item header a:contains('Private: ')").html(function(_, html) {
   return html.replace(/(Private: )/g, '<span class="smallcaps">$1</span>');
});
```

```
jQuery(".dwqa-question-item header a:contains('Private: )").wrapinner('<span />');
```

```
jQuery('.dwqa-question-item header a:contains("Private: ")').html(function(index, oldHTML) {
    return oldHTML.replace(/(Private: )/g, '<span>$&</span>');
});
```

Thank you.

Comment: First version [works fine here](https://jsfiddle.net/ky18hj02/) with exception of having to fix quotes on the `href`

Comment: Hi charlietfl: Wow, thank you for your help, your code works perfectly. Have a nice weekend  : )